# My render suddenly can't find any light's

Tags: rendering

Suddenly when i render, it has lost all it's light - but only in the beginning of the animation (frame 0 - approx.2391) The rest works fine.

hmm, I have som ideas about why it could have been. In my animation, when i don't need the light I keyframe it far far away in to a closed box? 
I think I also screwed up when setting a new camera, I accidently hit Ctrl-B on a wrong camera(can't remember which), and not the one before the new camera i had planned to put.

I have the file for my project here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4hoy0u2f0bgw8pc/Berenice%20Help%21.blend?dl=0

Really hope you can help!

Comment: to avoid this sort of issue in the future save regularly using "Save As" and click the [+] button by the "Save As Blender File" to create incremental changes myfile_001.blend, myfile_002.blend etc. I do this for the even the most trivial project after being caught out in the past.